# Issue with php contact form script?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I hope you can help!

Heres the issue, I have this php contact form script (as shown below) which I have used before so I know works, BUT, due to that I have hidden the html form inside of a new jQuery powered div:`(<div class="toggle hidemail" id="drop-button" href=""> Email us here </div> <div class="hidden hiddenform">)`
that toggles up and down, I cant seem to send the form at all, the form when sent is supposed to fade out then give the user a confirmation message (as shown in the script) but it doesn't do anything, I don't suppose anyone would know whats going wrong here so I can get this form working again? thank you!

```
    <?php

$to = 'example@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Company Name';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$body = <<<EMAIL

Hello my name is $name.

$message

From $name
my email address is $email


EMAIL;

if($name == '' || $email == '' || $message == "") {
    echo "<h5>Sorry, I think you missed  bit....</h5>";
    $error = true;
} else {
    $error = false;
    mail("example@gmail.com", $name, $email, $message);
    echo "<h5>Thank you for getting in touch. I'll get back to you ASAP.</h5>";
}


if($error == true):
?>

<article id="contact-form">

    <article id="load_area">

        <form id="my-form">

            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" /></textarea>
            <input type="button" class="submit_button" value="Send" name="send_button" />

        </form>

    </article>

</article>

<?php

endif;

?>
```

In the head tag:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".submit_button").live("click", function(){
            $("#load_area").fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $("#load_area").fadeIn();
            $.post("process.php", $("#my-form").serialize(), function(data){
                $("#load_area").html(data);
            })
            });
        })
    })
```

Here is the HTML :

```
 <div class="hidden hiddenform">

    <article id="contact-form">

        <article id="load_area">

            <form id="my-form">

                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" /></textarea>
                <input type="button" class="submit_button" value="Send" name="send_button" />

            </form>

        </article>

    </article>

</div>
```

Thank You!

Comment: Please do not post duplicates. Fix your previous post instead.